# Using AutoMapper Correctly

Tags: c#, automapper

I m trying to learn how to use AutoMapper, I m trying to figure out how to use without having to couple different layers.

Example, I have DataLayer, BusinessLayer and UILayer. 
To transfer/map from DataLayer to BusinessLayer, I have to have references in BusinessLayer to the DataLayer Entites.
The same happens if I try to To transfer/map from BusinessLayer to UILayer, in this case I would need to have references to the BusinessLayer from UILayer.

The solution here appears that we need an extra assembly (common/shared) between all layers that would do this automatically without needing to couple the DataLayer, BusinessLayer and UILayer with each other...

No sure how to do this, any example of this that I can use? How genereally this problem is addressed?

Comment: You generally define your models in a separate library de-coupled from the datalayer; business layer et al.  .

Comment: All you really need to do is just set up the configuration for the mappings between each pair of classes you want to map. Don't overthink it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you invert the dependency between layers, it doesn't seem that bad.

Introducing UI dependencies in your business layer would be ugly, but since UI layer is on top of business layer, it's fine that you *mix* UI and business layer there.

At the end of the day, *AutoMapper* replaces what you would do manually: setting properties one by one from an object to other one. *What would happen if you would do this without AutoMapper?* I believe that you would need a reference of *business layer* in your *UI layer* to perform such mapping.

Comment: Agree, AutoMapper is great, and I also agree with the UI having a reference to the BL, but what about the BL having references to the DL? My understanding is that everything should should "grow" around the BLL and not the other way round... 1 solution that I thought is to have the BL Entities traveling up and down through the BL and DL, but before I do that I wanted to know if there is a better solution?!

Comment: @J_PT Maybe you're wrong. The business layer is just another layer in your stack. It should be built on top of data layer and should be in the bottom of UI layer. It's not everything should grow *around* business layer. It's more about a clear separation of concerns and a concrete relationship/association between layers. The upper layer should depend on lower layer, and I assume that you're going this way. That is, you're in the right track :D

Comment: I m searching for a solution that implements abstraction between layers regarding to the Entities on each layer.

Comment: @j_pt this doesn't exist at all. You think that layers equal to visual studio protects, but layers are just conceptual things. I mean that instead of separating mapping configurations on some new projects you should keep it simple and just configure mappings in a specific class.

Comment: @j_pt or in other words, you're coupling layers even when you separate the same operation in different projects. Projects are just a compilation detail. A good design is about how your system works when you execute it